# android opencart php restapi

Tags: php, android, rest, opencart

I've created an Android application for opencart

In this program, I send two parameters to rest api
But i can not see the parameters in api

I am not receiving any parameters that are sent from Android app

**android Code as follows:**

```
private void getProductCart() {
    var1url= "http://www.my-site-name.com/?route=feed/web_api2/cart_products";
    MainActivity.this.kindvar1=1;

    StringRequest var2request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, var1url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        public void onResponse(String var1json) {


            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationDrawer.class));
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError var1error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + var1error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            VolleyError error= var1error;
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
            }

            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
            }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
            }


            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }) {
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap auth = new HashMap();
            auth.put("Accept", ConstFile.Param1);
            auth.put("Authorization", ConstFile.Param2);
            return auth;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("token", MainActivity.this.access_token_code);
            params.put("kindvar1", MainActivity.this.kindvar1+"");
            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(var2request, "productcartItems");
}
```

**and php web api Code as follows:**
web_api2.php and its functions

```
        <?php
    class ControllerFeedWebApi2 extends Controller {
      private $debug = false;


      public function cart_products() {

        if (isset($this->request->get['token'])) {
          $token = $this->request->get['token'];
        }
        else {
          $token = 'd9f595ae2c9b482857e250a2aa310a1c';
        }

         if ( isset($this->request->get['kindvar1'])) {
          $kindvar1 = (int)$this->request->get['kindvar1'];
         }
        else {
          $kindvar1 = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $this->load->model('account/wishlist');
        $this->load->model('account/api');

        $json = array();


        $api_info1 = $this->model_account_api->GetCustomer_idByToken($token);


        $customer_id = $api_info1['customer_id']  ;



      if($kindvar1 >0)
      {
        $json['settings'] = array();

     $json['settings'] = array(
     'kindvar1' => $kindvar1,
     'title'    => 'persian shop',
     'name'     => 'arya club',
     'owner'    => $customer_id
     );

      }


        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

      }

      public function categoriesNew() {
        $this->init();
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
         if (isset($this->request->get['parent'])) {
          $parent = $this->request->get['parent'];
          if (!is_numeric($parent)){
             settype($parent,"integer");
          }
        }
        else {
          $parent = 0;
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['level'])) {
          $level = $this->request->get['level'];
          if (!is_numeric($level)){
             settype($level,"integer");
          }
        }
        else {
          $level = 4;
        }
        $json['categories'] = $this->getCategoriesTreeNew($parent, $level);

        if ($this->debug) {
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($json);
        }
        else {
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

        }
      }


      public function products() {
        $this->init();
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $json = array('success' => true, 'products' => array());
        if (isset($this->request->get['category'])) {
          $category_id = $this->request->get['category'];
        }
        else {
          $category_id = 0;
        }
       $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $category_id));
        foreach ($products as $product) {
          if ($product['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
          }
          else {
            $image = false;
          }
          if ((float) $product['special']) {
            $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['special'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
          }
          else {
            $special = false;
          }
          if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
            $siteaddress = $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/';
          }
          else {
            $siteaddress = $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/';
          }

          $product_id = $product['product_id'];
          $productx = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
          $additional_images = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($productx['product_id']);
          $images = array();
          foreach ($additional_images as $additional_image) {
           $images[] = $siteaddress . $additional_image['image'];
          }

          $json['products'][] = array('id' => $product['product_id'], 'name' => $product['name'], 'price' => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))), 'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']), 'thumb' => $image, 'imageurl' => $siteaddress . $product['image'], 'imagesurl' => $images, 'special' => $special, 'description' => $product['description'], 'rating' => $product['rating']);
        }
        if ($this->debug) {
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($json);
        }
        else {
          $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }
      }

      private function getCategoriesTreeNew($parent = 0, $level = 1) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $result = array();
        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($parent);

        if ($categories && $level > 0) {
          $level--;
          foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $total_product = 44;
            if ($category['image']) {
              $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
            }
            else {
              $image = false;
    $nullberaket=array(); 
    $nextlevel=$this->getCategoriesTreeNew((int)$category['category_id'], $level);
    $nextlevel1 = is_null($nextlevel) ? $nullberaket : $nextlevel;      
            $result[] = array(
            'category_id' => (int)$category['category_id'], 
            'name' => $category['name'], 
            'description' => $category['description'],
            'thumb_image' => $image , 
            'total_products' => $total_product, 
            'categories' => $nextlevel1
            );

          }

          return $result;
        }
      }

    }
```

please help me, What's wrong

Comment: First Of, make sure your Rest API is returning the right values. Then we'll know when to start checking your issues. Whether its in the API or Your Java Class. Please verify first !

Comment: yes. when i use http://www.myexample.com/?route=feed/web_api2/cart_products&kindvar1=2 the api works

Comment: you can check my api in aryaclub.com/?route=feed/web_api2/cart_products&kindvar1=2